# Declare additional dependency to sphinx-build in an extension

Tags: python-sphinx, build-dependencies

TL,DR: From a Sphinx extension, how do I tell `sphinx-build` to treat an additional file as a dependency? In my immediate use case, this is the extension's source code, but the question could equally apply to some auxiliary file used by the extension.

I'm generating documentation with Sphinx using a custom extension. I'm using `sphinx-build` to build the documentation. For example, I use this command to generate the HTML (this is the command in the makefile generated by `sphinx-quickstart`):

```
sphinx-build -b html -d _build/doctrees   . _build/html
```

Since my custom extension is maintained together with the source of the documentation, I want `sphinx-build` to treat it as a dependency of the generated HTML (and LaTeX, etc.). So whenever I change my extension's source code, I want `sphinx-build` to regenerate the output.

**How do I tell `sphinx-build` to treat an additional file as a dependency?** That is not mentioned in the toctree, since it isn't part of the source. Logically, this should be something I do from my extension's `setup` function.

---

Sample extension (`my_extension.py`):

```python
from docutils import nodes
from docutils.parsers.rst import Directive

class Foo(Directive):
    def run(self):
        node = nodes.paragraph(text='Hello world\n')
        return [node]

def setup(app):
    app.add_directive('foo', Foo)
```

Sample source (`index.rst`):

```rst
.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 2

.. foo::
```

Sample `conf.py` (basically the output of `sphinx-quickstart` plus my extension):

```python
import sys
import os
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('.'))
extensions = ['my_extension']
templates_path = ['_templates']
source_suffix = '.rst'
master_doc = 'index'
project = 'Hello directive'
copyright = '2019, Gilles'
author = 'Gilles'
version = '1'
release = '1'
language = None
exclude_patterns = ['_build']
pygments_style = 'sphinx'
todo_include_todos = False
html_theme = 'alabaster'
html_static_path = ['_static']
htmlhelp_basename = 'Hellodirectivedoc'
latex_elements = {
}
latex_documents = [
    (master_doc, 'Hellodirective.tex', 'Hello directive Documentation',
     'Gilles', 'manual'),
]
man_pages = [
    (master_doc, 'hellodirective', 'Hello directive Documentation',
     [author], 1)
]
texinfo_documents = [
    (master_doc, 'Hellodirective', 'Hello directive Documentation',
     author, 'Hellodirective', 'One line description of project.',
     'Miscellaneous'),
]
```

Validation of a solution:

1. Run `make html` (or `sphinx-build` as above).
2. Modify `my_extension.py` to replace `Hello world` by `Hello again`.
3. Run `make html` again.
4. The generated HTML (`_build/html/index.html`) must now contain `Hello again` instead of `Hello world`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the [`note_dependency` method in the build environment API](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/extdev/envapi.html#sphinx.environment.BuildEnvironment.note_dependency) should do what I want. But when should I call it? I tried various [events](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/extdev/appapi.html#events) but none seemed to hit the environment object in the right state. What did work was to call it from a directive.

```
import os
from docutils import nodes
from docutils.parsers.rst import Directive
import sphinx.application

class Foo(Directive):
    def run(self):
        self.state.document.settings.env.note_dependency(__file__)
        node = nodes.paragraph(text='Hello done\n')
        return [node]

def setup(app):
    app.add_directive('foo', Foo)
```

If a document contains at least one `foo` directive, it'll get marked as stale when the extension that introduces this directive changes. This makes sense, although it could get tedious if an extension adds many directives or makes different changes. I don't know if there's a better way.

Inspired by [Luc Van Oostenryck's autodoc-C](https://github.com/lucvoo/autodoc-C/blob/master/cdoc.py).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know `app.env.note_dependency` can be called within the `doctree-read` to add any file as a dependency to the document currently being read.
So in your use case, I assume this would work:

```
from typing import Any, Dict
from sphinx.application import Sphinx
import docutils.nodes as nodes


def doctree-read(app: Sphinx, doctree: nodes.document):
    app.env.note_dependency(file)


def setup(app: Sphinx):
    app.connect("doctree-read", doctree-read)
```